# Android: Keeping Image Visible Throughout Animation

Tags: android, animation, button, z-order

**Background:**
I have an Activity that comprises four buttons that each take up a quarter of the screen.
It contains a horizontal LinearLayout that is divided in half by two vertical LinearLayouts as shown in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Wd3.jpg

**Desired Effect:**
When I touch a button, I would like it to animate and fill up the entire screen.

**Issue:**
I have accomplished the animation aspect by changing X and Y scales from 1 to 2 onClick.
The problem is, however, that the animated button will not show when it leaves its parent LinearLayout.

**Thoughts**

1. I have tried making the non-animated buttons invisible, but the animated button will only show in its parent LinearLayout.
2. I know this problem would be solved if I had used a single LinearLayout, but I was unable to use the "layout:weight" feature to make each button take up half of both width and length.

**So...** How should I approach this issue?

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: did u tried dynamically changing parent layout weight to 100 so that also will fill fully in main parent layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a single `RelativeLayout`. Check [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/) for a nice example. You may have to  `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` for the other buttons.

**Alternative:**

1. Construct a `RelativeLayout` as above but put that as the only child
   of a `FrameLayout`.
2. When animating a button, [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) it from the `RelativeLayout` and [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) it to the `FrameLayout` specifying the gravity in the [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#FrameLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20int%29) appropriately. This way the rest of the buttons will also be seen in the background during the animation.